# Trying to migrate from androidx to appcompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat, androidx

I created a new project with Android Studio but it has created this project with **androidX** Facets.

I have tried to migrate from **androidx** to **appcomat** but it shows no uses. I've tried manually to change it but it's not helping.

Comment: appcompat has been updated to androidx. The APIs are pretty much the same, you should work the same way with androidx.

Comment: Thank you but my previous project is in appcompat its pretty old i have tried it on androidx already there are a lot of errors that why i am trying to follow old steps

Comment: Usually, there will be errors on migration to Androidx. Those errors are usually due to old imports(support) of classes, you simply have to re-import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow

---

> Try to migrate that project From AndroidX to Appcompat

[image]

---

> In anycase if that does not help you can try manually
>   Change app grade from 
>   [image: app.gradle of AndroidX]

[image: app.gradle of Appcompat]

---

> Change Activity main

[image: Androidx main activity]

[image: Activity main of appcompat]

> Last Thing resources file
>   [image: AndroidX res]
>   [image: Appcompat res]

Best Regards
Ahmed